# MEF only loading Exports from local assembly

Tags: export, mef

Im trying to make an app that can dynamically load classes that implements an interface "IPlugin", i have:

```
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Shell).Assembly);
        var externalCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\Modules");

        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);


        var a = new AggregateCatalog(externalCatalog, catalog);
```

But when im trying to get the exports:

```
        CompositionContainer __container = new CompositionContainer(a);
        //get all the exports and load them into the appropriate list tagged with the importmany
        __container.Compose(batch);

        var yyyy = __container.GetExports<IModule>();
```

It doesnt find my "IPlugin" in the external assembly "Rejseplan".

---

Implementation of "Rejseplan" plugin:(the one that does not get loaded)

```
 namespace Rejseplan
 {

[ModuleExport(typeof(IPlugin), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]
class RejseplanModule : IModule, IPlugin
{
     private readonly IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry;

    [ImportingConstructor]
     public RejseplanModule(IRegionViewRegistry registry)
    {
        this.regionViewRegistry = registry;   
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(Views.DepartureBoard));       
    }

    string IPlugin.Name
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    string IPlugin.Version
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    string IPlugin.TabHeader
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
}
```

implmentation of "Test" plugin (the one that GETS loaded):

```
  namespace HomeSystem
    {
     [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
    [ModuleExport(typeof(IModule), InitializationMode =   InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]
    public class Test : IModule, IPlugin
    {
    public void Initialize()
    {

    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Test"; }
    }

    public string Version
    {
        get { return "Tis"; }
    }

    public string TabHeader
    {
        get { return "Tabt"; }
    }
}
```

}

 Hope you guys can help
Cheers! :)

Comment: do you recieve an error or does the catalog is just not list your plugin?

Comment: I get all the parts in my catalog, the list of my plugins returns only the ones within the shells dll

Comment: An important remark: the dll is loaded and the module os shown in its region within the program - so the module is loaded and works fine - but i cant get the instance of the module and work with its data from the shell - (i want to show some data in the shell about the module)

Comment: why you create two compositioncontainer? you only need one but with both catalogs.

Comment: Sorry for the uncleary code - there is only one container, the second was just something i had for testing another theory ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be honest i dont really know what you wanna achieve :) 
but if you want to see your RejseplanModule within your call:

```
__container.GetExports<IModule>();
```

you have to add the right Export attribute.

RejseplanModule is not MEF marked with Export of type IModule. can you check your code if its a typo or not? at least it should be the following (see the typeof(**IModule**))

EDIT:

external dll

```
[Export(typeof(IModule))]//<-- remove this if its handled by your custom ModulExport Attribute
[ModuleExport(typeof(IModule), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]
class RejseplanModule : IModule, IPlugin
{...}
```

your main app(code from fhnaseer above)

```
var directoryPath = "path to dll folder";
var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directoryPath, "*.dll");

var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(asmCatalog);
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

var allIModulPlugins = container.GetExports<IModule>();
```

Comment: well, i simply want to get all instances of Imodule interface.. But when i try using [import] Lazy<Imodule>() - nothing happens, so i tried to obtain the instances through a container..

Comment: your Rejseplan modul is not marked for Export of type IModul.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this.

```
var directoryPath = "path to dll folder";
var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directoryPath, "*.dll");

var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(asmCatalog);
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Comment: It returns the same.. I have set the initmode to whenAvailable - so i figure that the external assembly is already loaded when the shell is executing?

Comment: try to do it without initialization mode. whan happenes then.